# Do these Healing items for the cleric stack when she uses her healing powers?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, cleric

One of my players came to me with his ultimate wish-list for the cleric he found on the internet.  But I'm wondering do all these healing powers stack, here's the list of items:

**Healer's Brooch** (AV pg152)

> **Property**: When you use a power that
>   enables you or an ally to regain hit
>   points, add the brooch's enhancement
>   bonus to the hit points gained.

**Healer's Armor**

> **Property**: When you use a healing
>   power, the target regains additional
>   hit points equal to the armor's
>   enhancement bonus.

**Mace of Healing**

> **Property**: When you use a power that restores hit points to an ally,
>   add an item bonus equal to this
>   weapon's enhancement bonus to the
>   amount restored.

**Gloves of the Healer**

> **Property:**  When you use a power that has the healing keyword, one target regains an > extra 1d6 hit points.  Level 22: 2d6 hit points.

Comment: Something to note, is that quite a few healing related things (mostly feats) underwent errata recently to only trigger on healing that cost the target a healing surge, but I don't know if that errata applied to these items.

Comment: You are correct, I know at least the healer's brooch is modified in that manner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, they stack.

The mace adds an item bonus, the others are untyped.  Only similar typed bonuses would not stack.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good answer on the guidelines for resolving stacking here: 
[Stacking Resolution](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5618/is-there-a-limit-to-racial-magic-item-feats-powers-you-can-stack-on-a-singl)