# Enlarged Dragon Breath & Hurl Breath

Tags: dnd-4e

While I am assuming that Hurl Breath would continue unchanged, does having the *Enlarged Dragon Breath* feat have any affect upon the AoE of *Hurl Breath*?  The EDB was created first and thus wouldn't include it in its description, and HB was created after but oversights have happened before.

> **Enlarged Dragon Breath**
>
> > When you use your dragon breath power, you can choose to make it blast 5 instead of blast 3.

---

> **Hurl Breath**
>
> > When you use your dragon breath, you can choose to make it an area burst 2 within 10 squares instead of a close blast 3.

Now, the reason I stumbled on this is because I'm building a Dragonborn Warlord, and very intent on using:

> **Inspiring Breath**
>
> > When you hit an enemy using your dragon breath racial power, your allies gain a +5 bonus to damage rolls against that enemy until the end of your next turn.

So regardless of how the object feats play together, I'm likely going to include both along the way anyhow (it's a level 5 character).

Answer (score 5):

It would have no effect because *Hurl Breath* doesn't say you can increase the blast by one and turn it into a burst within 10. It specifically says turn it into a burst 2. And *Enlarged Dragon Breath* does not say it increases the size of your *Dragon Breath* power by 2, it specifically lists what the change is to.

*Hurl Breath* would be the superior feat. Since aside from the blast/burst keywords which could I guess potentially matter for some rare protections against those specific keywords, *Hurl Breath* can do everything that *Enlarged Dragon Breath* can do.

Comment: *Hurl Breath* generates AoOs, while *Enlarged Dragon Breath* doesn't. If we exclude that your last sentence is right.

Comment: @Zachiel I assumed all of the effects were listed in CatLord's question.

Answer (score 1):

Looked up all the feats in question here. They apply to the base dragon breath attack. My interpretation is that these all stack on each other and would be expressed as a 4 square AoE with in 10 squares (Hurl Breath's -1 sq penalty taken from Enlarged Breath's 5 sq area).

The following is a link to a similar question, in which the chosen best answer lists pages for the rules on stacking bonuses (p275 PHB1 and p223 PHB3)
[Is there a limit to racial - magic item - feats - powers you can stack on a single standard action attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5618/is-there-a-limit-to-racial-magic-item-feats-powers-you-can-stack-on-a-sing)

In short the untyped bonuses will stack unless it's for the same power, feat, etc. In my reading of the rules for these specific feats (which don't specify 'feat power' and therefore are 'untyped') relating to dragon's breath... I don't consider them both 'bonuses'. Hurl Breath includes a penalty, which I think disqualifies it from being a pure bonus. Therefore, applying Enlarged breath first, making it 5 squares, then applying Hurl Breath (which is essentially -1 to the AoE to gain range) makes it a 4sq AoE with a 10 sq range.

So while DampeS8N wasn't wrong saying Hurl Breath can do anything Enlarged Breath can do; if you consider the thought's I have had on the subject, you effectively CAN increase the damage area (and the area in which Inspiring Breath works).

*EDIT: Note that the descriptions of these feats are worded with "...you can choose to make..." added in them. Therefore you don't always have to hurl your breath, and you don't always have to enlarge the breath attacks. So even if you want to interpret the rules as black and white like DampeS8N, and say that it has to be the stated "5sq" not "+2sq", for example; you still can take both and use them interchangeably in conjunction with Inspiring Breath to hit the max number of assailants for the best Inspiring breath bonus.

Comment: Both feats *explicitly* add a size option. If you have both feats, you can choose from close blast 3, close blast 5, or area burst 2 every time you use dragon breath, but you can't combine the two feats. Enlarged Dragon Breath doesn't say, "increase the size of your breath's area by 2", it says "you can make it a blast 5 instead of a blast 3". Likewise, Hurl Breath doesn't say, "you can use dragon breath as an area burst 1 size smaller than its normal size", it says you can use it as an area burst 2. Neither effect modifies the existing size, they offer additional sizes instead.